# How to render reports by code (C#) in CRM 2011 ADFS or Online-deployments?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, adfs2.0

How can I render reports by code (C#) in CRM 2011 ADFS or Online-deployments?

A customer is moving their solution to a "private cloud", that is partner hosted using ADFS 2.0 and claims based authentication only. However, they have an application that each month generate reports for each account and sends this as Excel-attachment to several CRM contacts. The problem now is how to generate the reports automatically by code?

With AD deployment it is possible to contact the Reporting Services-service directly to render reports (to excel, pdf etc). But how can I do this with CRM 2011 and ADFS? It will be possible for me to get access to reporting services through the use of VPN but what about authentication? Also, how would customers that use Microsoft Online solve this?

Comment: did you find a method of doing this?